# Bad redirection with virtual method

Tags: c++, class

I have 2 classes A and B, where B inherit from A. Inside A, I have this method `virtual int save(X *) const =0`. Inside B, I want this method `virtual int save(Y *) const`

I have also class X and Y, where Y inherit from X.

But then the compiler says I can't make an instance of B because it is abstract. Why this doesn't work? The compiler can't see that Y inherit from X?

Answer (score 1):

The type signatures of the functions need to match. You can't use polymorphism in the parameters when overriding a function like that. As far as the compiler is concerned, now `B` has *two* methods, `virtual int save(X *) const =0` and `virtual int save(Y *) const` ([where the second is hiding the first](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html)). Since the function signatures don't match, the second one isn't actually overriding it; it's just hiding it.

Comment: `B` doesn't have two `save` methods - `B::save` _hides_ `A::save`, it does not _overload_ it.

Comment: But If i do A.save(y), it does not go on `save` from B.

Comment: @Eran it does have two methods. The fact that one is hidden just makes it harder to call; it still exists. You're right they aren't overloads.

Comment: Try also compiling the program in C++11 mode, and add `override` to `B::save(Y *)`'s signature. You'll get a nice `error: ‘virtual int B::f(Y*) const’ marked override, but does not override` (GCC).

Comment: @eran: indeed, thanks for catching my misnomer. But it does have two methods (but yes, my use of "overload" was incorrect/misleading).

Answer (score 0):

The abstract method in `A` can accept any `X` pointer. If you want to override it you have to accept everything the original method does. Your method which only handles pointers to `Y` doesn't do that.

Comment: C++ supports contravariant parameters?!  Are you sure?

Comment: Gah, of course not. Covariant return types yes, contravariant parameters no. Too much Java rots the brain.