# Polymorphic overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, polymorphism, overriding

I have a parent class A which has two child classes (B and C). I then have the following virtual function in A:

```
virtual void X(boost::shared_ptr<A> a) = 0;
```

and in the two child classes which extend the parent class I override `X()`:

```
void X(boost::shared_ptr<B> b);
```

and

```
void X(boost::shared_ptr<C> c);
```

is it definitely possible to do this because I am encountering problems and not even sure if the standard allows this?

Comment: When overriding virtual functions, C++ supports co-variant result types, but doesn't support co-variant argument types. Note however, that even if the latter were supported, it wouldn't work in your case, as `shared_ptr<Base>` and `shared_ptr<Derived>` are unrelated types.

Comment: @IgorR. are you sure because my compiler seems to act as if they are related?

Comment: `shread_ptr<Derived>` is *convertible* to `shared_ptr<Base>`, due to a  type-cast operator. But these classes are unrelated, as they are just instantiations of `shared_ptr` template with different template parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was talked about recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020849/bad-redirection-with-virtual-method). You aren't overriding it. [You're hiding it](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html).

It's not possible to override a function like that. The function signatures *have* to match when overriding.

Comment: consider the use of the CRTP